# Lipschitz Continuity in one variable of a several variable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

The question seems to be a rather harmless one, yet till now I am unable to come up with any proof or counterexample!! The question is the following.

> Prove or disprove : If $F(x,y)$ is a $C^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ function such that $F$ is Lipschitz continuous in $y$-variable, then $F_{x}(x,y)$ is also Lipschitz continuous in $y$-variable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try $f(x,y) = \sin(xy)$ where $f_x(x,y) =  y\cos(xy)$.

Comment: But $f$ is not Lipschitz in $y$-variable, as its $y$-derivative is unbounded on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @user357151 I wasn't sure if the Lipschitz constant needs to be independent of $x$. Then $f(x,y) = \sin(\sin(x) y)$ would work.